# java.util.logging.publish does not get called

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I have implemented `java.util.logging.Handler` (LogHandler) and my Wildfly configuration is pretty much vanilla. Everything is fine and works as expected. The idea is now, to split the logging part into two files. What I have done is the following:

```
      <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="PROTOCOL" autoflush="true">
         <level name="INFO"/>
         <formatter>
             <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
         </formatter>
         <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="protocol.log"/>
         <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
         <append value="true"/>
     </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
     ...
     <logger category="com.test.transport" use-parent-handlers="false">
         <level name="INFO"/>
         <handlers>
            <handler name="PROTOCOL"/>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
         </handlers>
     </logger>
```

Works as expected as well, I got another file with the log from `com.test.transport`.

My problem is, since I have changed my wildfly configuration, everything in the PROTOCOL log file does not get published by my LogHandler.

Edit:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class LogHandler extends ExtHandler {
   @Override
   public void publish(LogRecord record) {
     String message = record.getMessage();
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define your `LogHandler`? The `PROTOCOL` logger above is a `org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodiceRotatingFileHandler`.

Comment: That is true, that could be a problem. I have taken a deeper look into it, but if I change it to `ExtHandler` it is still the same.
I have noticed a second "strange" behaviour. If I debug into it, it holds in the publish method for every other log-message. But the log-message from transport is printed by another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to split your application log messages into a separate file what you have, minus your `LogHandler` should do that.

If you want to use your own log handler you need to install it as a module. See the CLI `module add --help` for details. There is no way to have custom handlers in your deployment. They need to be defined as modules.

You then need to add the handler as a [custom-handler](http://wildscribe.github.io/Wildfly/8.2.0.Final/subsystem/logging/custom-handler/index.html) to the logging subsystem.

Here's some example commands to add the module and create the custom handler.

```
module add --name=com.test.transport --resources=/path/to/jar/transport-logging.jar

/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=PROTOCOL:add(class=com.test.transport.LogHandler, module=com.test.transport, level=INFO, named-formatter=PATTERN, properties={file="${jboss.server.log.dir}/protocol.log"})

/subsystem=logging/logger=com.test.transport:add(level=INFO, use-parent-handlers=false, handlers=[CONSOLE, PROTOCOL])
```

Comment: Let's say the publish method has no logic at all. Why does it work if I dont split the logfiles into two files? The publish method is called for every log message and is not defined as a module?

Comment: Are you talking about the `publish(LogRecord)` method in your `LogHandler` class? I don't see how that would ever be called unless you set it up as a module and a custom handler.

Comment: That has worked as expected, thanks :-). But I think there is a small mistake in your cli script? `properties={file="${jboss.server.log.dir}/protocol.log"}` has not worked for me(Wildfly 9). But it is not necessary for me at the moment, if you have to take a depper look into it, save your time :D